# Output plot with tics labels inside and without any margins/padding with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Using the following one-liner:

```
gnuplot -e 'set terminal png font ",7" size 300,200 ; \
set output "out.png"; \
set tics in; \
set obj 1 rect behind from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 ; \
set obj 1 fs fc rgb "gray" ; \
plot sin(x)'
```

I get this output:

[image: gpout.png]

What I want is:

- Both tics and labels inside the plot
- No margins/padding - so that the plot takes the full requested size

... that is, something like this:

[image: gpout_wanted.png]

(this image was scaled composited in gimp, so ignore the changes in color and apparent resolution)

Any ways to achieve something like this in `gnuplot`?

Comment: If using the `png` terminal, you might want to consider the `crop` option too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might want to try to tweak this

```
set lmargin at screen 0
set rmargin at screen 1
set tmargin at screen 1
set bmargin at screen 0
set xtics offset 0, screen 0.1
set ytics offset screen 0.1, 0
plot sin(x)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @bibi - just tried it, works great. Cheers!